# Crear div sticky con respecto a otro

Tags: jquery, css, html5, bootstrap

me explico. Estoy creando un div que se mantenga en la pagina al hacer scroll, el div ya funciona y es sticky, pero una parte de este div se oculta con el header navbar, quiero hacer que el div sea sticky hasta topar con header navbar y así el div pueda verse completo.

Este es el css que uso para hacer el div sticky:

```
.divsticky 
{
 position: -webkit-sticky; 
 position: sticky;
 top: 0;
}
```

Este es el HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row" id="rowid">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 p-0" id="barralateral">
        <div class="bdrs-3 ov-h bd divsticky" id="divcontenedorstikcy" >
            <div class="ta-c p-30" id="titulocontenedor">
                <h1>Texto</h1>
                <h3>Texto</h3>
            </div>
            <div style="overflow: auto;" id="contenedorid"><div class="pos-r">
                    <h5 id="events-list-header" class="text-center m-0 pt-1"></h5>
                    <ul class="m-0 p-0 mt-1" id="events-list"> </ul>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-9" id="content"></div>
</div>
```

Quiero hacer que el div con la clase ".divsticky" sea sticky pero que parte de este no sea ocultado por el header navbar.
Gracias:)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿El tamaño del header y del navbar es fijo?

Comment: Si, el tamaño el tamaño del header y del navbar es fijo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

lo que tenes que hacer es crear un contenedor para tu `divsticky`, este va a ser estatico, esto hace en modo que el `divsticky` sea pegajoso con su contenedor, el cual va a estar pegado al header pero no se va a esconder por debajo del mismo.

ejemplo :

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body{
  height: 200vh;
}
header{
  background: rgba(114, 186, 94, 0.45);
  height: 100px;
}
#contenedordivsticky{
  height: 400px;
  background: rgba(114, 186, 94, 0.05);
}
.divsticky 
{
 position: -webkit-sticky; 
 position: sticky;
 top: 4rem;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark sticky-top">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row" id="rowid">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 p-0" id="barralateral">
      <div id="contenedordivsticky">
          <div class="bdrs-3 ov-h bd divsticky" >
              <div class="ta-c p-30" id="titulocontenedor">
                  <h1>Texto</h1>
                  <h3>Texto</h3>
              </div>
              <div style="overflow: auto;" id="contenedorid"><div class="pos-r">
                      <h5 id="events-list-header" class="text-center m-0 pt-1"></h5>
                      <ul class="m-0 p-0 mt-1" id="events-list"> </ul>
                  </div>

              </div>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-9" id="content"></div>
</div>
```

**edite el codigo, miralo en pantalla completa para apreciar mejor el funcionamiento**

espero que te sea de ayuda

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, ¿también se podría hacer si el HEADER fuera sticky?

Comment: @AlfredoJosueBoche si tambien, en ese caso el contenedor tendria que tener `position: absolute;` y `top` = a la altura del header (si tiene una altura fija )

Comment: Gracias, agregue una imagen de como va quedando, pero el divsticky sigue ocultando una parte debajo del nabvar :s

Comment: @AJB ahí edite el codigo, proba asi y haceme saber :) (dandole un `top` al elemento `divsticky` )

Comment: Sí, es exactamente lo que buscaba, muchas gracias, por la ayuda y tu tiempo. :)